# Помогите разобраться в логике Django

Tags: python, django

Не совсем понимаю логику Django

Если быть точнее, то я понял, что нужны разные приложения, которые независимы друг от друга. Но это подходит для полноценных сайтов.

В моем случае, у меня стоит задача сделать личный кабинет, по сути это и будет одним только приложением, как я понимаю.

Но трудность заключается в том, что в этом приложении будет 4 роли, например:

- Главный админ (он должен управлять всем через админку, и видит все, что делают юзеры в данный момент или делали)
- Координатор (у него определенный набор возможных операций в личном кабинете, но он видит, что делают его менеджеры)
- менеджер - урезанный функционал, но свой, который визуально будет отличаться от первых двух ролей
- клиент ( некий dashboard для клиента, с различными опциями внутри)

И чтобы это все работало в одной панели управления адрессайта.ру/login/
и каждая роль видела только свой интерфейс при авторизации

И я вот не совсем понимаю структуру... мне нужно под каждую роль делать отдельный template, или же каждая роль это отдельное приложение в рамках django или это все настраивается во views с разными наборами нужных функций, но для каждой роли отдельно, а после подключается все в блок if user admin - то он видит вот это и тд.

никак не могу найти ответа на этот вопрос. С точки зрения своей логики, я понимаю как это должно выглядеть, но как это правильно реализовать посредством django - вообще нет понимания. Всю информацию которую находил описывает общие принципы и в рамках нескольких моделей на сайт (блог, новости, каталог) но в рамках одного приложения, ничего подобного не находил

Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос ну крайне простой

Comment: Вообще, подобные вещи решаются установкой прав для разных категорий пользователей. вот, например, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Comment: @strawdog тут проблема в том, что у каждой категории, должно быть свое отображение на экране, и оно сильно отличается друг от друга. И тут нет понимания как это реализовать

Comment: Это не является проблемой. На основании привелегий пользователя вы просто подгружаете соответствующий шаблон в шаблон своей страницы.

Comment: @strawdog ну т.е. я верно мыслил на счет 1 приложения + приложение авторизации + 4 tempate под каждую группу пользователей

Comment: совершенно верно.

Comment: @strawdog Большое спасибо